# How to return different strings from a Boolean type in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

If I have a column set up as Boolean in MySql, a query returns the value as either `0` or `1`.

Is it possible to do something like this

```
SELECT `bool_value` AS "yes" OR "no"
```

What I mean is, return two different strings based on whether it is true or false.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN bool_value <> 0 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END
```

Answer (score 32):

You need the `case` statement.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN column <> 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) As Value
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 31):

MySql supports the standdard SQL CASE statement, which other answers use. MySQL also has the shorter, but non-standard IF statement

```
SELECT IF(bool_value,'Yes','No')
```

See

- [MySQL Flow Control Functions: IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)