# How to get String value from a boolean value using MySQL query in Jasper Studio

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have an SQL query to get results from my database table. When I run this query in `Jasper Studio` it should bring me following.

`Nocte` & `Mane` are boolean type colomns in the table. If the `Nocte` column is `true` then, it could show as a string ("Nocte") and this should same for the `mane`.

**SQL Query**

```
select * from medication where $X{IN,idmedication,list} order by `LastUpdated` desc
```

This is the query I am using in Jasper report and `idmedication` and `list` are parameters. `LastUpdated` is a `timestamp`. This `list` includes `Integer` values, which are the `idMedications`.

Have any ideas to do above task in `Jasper Studio`?

Comment: If you like to do in query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359374/how-to-return-different-strings-from-a-boolean-type-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two approaches at the moment:

1. Use expressions when you design the report, it could be something like `($F{Nocte}?"Nocte":"something else")`
2. Modify the query so that it returns `varchar` instead of `boolean`. For example:

   ```
   select case when Nocte = 1 then "Nocte" else "something else" end Nocte
   from your_table ...
   ```

Comment: Actually I should use my mysql query . How could I use these both in same time ?

Comment: You don't have to use both at the same time as they both serve the same purpose. If you modify the query, then it will return you a 'varchar' (which will be a 'String' in the report), and you can directly display it in a **TextField** (in Jasper Reports).

Comment: @TurikMirash, hi I modified your post some, removed ==true (not need since boolean and added the outer (), so it's recognized as an expression if used in String concatenation.., you can rollback if you don't like it

Comment: @PetterFriberg, thanks! No need to roll it back, yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is something like bellow

```
(
   ${your_filed_name}==true?"Nocte"":"mane"
)
```

Hope this answer your question. And you can chain the condition or get into more complex expression.